# Copy Or Reference assignment of Class Module

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a task where I am just creating stub modules and stub Class modules for an excel spreadsheet that will loop through specific cells that contain an Excel vba macro name.  I am trying to either copy or reference a class module.  Either solution works since I am just creating stubs.  The current goal is to just get some strings within the macros that are executed.  Unfortunately, I have a restriction where I am unable to modify the vba code that is provided to me already.

Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to achieve.

```
' Class1 code
Public x As Integer

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
End Sub
Private Sub Class_Terminate()
End Sub

' Module1 Code

Function Copy_Class() As Class1
    Set Copy_Class = New Class1
    Copy_Class.x = 231
End Function

Sub testing_class_copy_or_reference()
    Dim orig_class As New Class1

    orig_class = Copy_Class ' <- Fails here
    Debug.Print orig_class.x
End Sub
```

I do have a workaround fix and that is to do `Set orig_class = Copy_Class` but, again, the goal is to not have to modify the provided vba macros.

Comment: I'm confused, why can you not modify an erroneous line?

Comment: The goal is to be a sort of plugin and just run a specified set of cells with no modification to their excel spreadsheet vba code.  I'm unable to modify the spreadsheet that is provided to me because the vba code is our clients.

Comment: Ok, but `orig_class = Copy_Class` is clearly erroneous, that needs fixed with `Set` as you noted.

Comment: The vba code provided does not have a ```Set``` within it.  I just have to work around it, unfortunately

Comment: So, you're saying that there is a bug in the vba macro code that is provided?

Comment: Yes, there clearly is.

Comment: I thought so but I am also wondering if this is due to a compatibility issue between my Office 365 excel application compared to whatever version of Excel that the spreadsheet was originated in.  Is the me requiring the ```Set``` due to a true bug or a vba compilation compatibility issue?

Comment: Objects require `Set`, period. Has nothing to do with Office 365.

Comment: All of the vba code provided that has this particular copy/reference functionality do not utilize the ```Set```.  I'm thinking that I shouldn't be utilizing a Class Module but another Data Structure that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Maybe a `Type` but hard to know for sure.

Comment: You can't do ```New <TypeName>``` in vba code.  The actual macro has ```Dim var_object as New ObjectName``` with about 100 lines of code not accessing that variable until the ```var_object = object1.object2...object6.FunctionReturnsSomething``` with no Set.  This happens in about 20 different other macros, too.  I'll just do some more research with vba's data structures but I've tried a lot of different things to no avail...  Is there a way to use Set or Let in a class that will copy over the data?  I haven't been able to find the syntax, if it is possible.

Comment: Is there an actual class module? Or is that what you've created? Or both? I wasn't sure what code you provided was actually yours, or provided to you. Maybe if you provided the *actual* class module, we'd be able to help. But from what's in the question, it's a bit difficult.

Comment: None that are provided.  As I've mentioned in the root post, I'm creating stubs for all these class references that are used throughout the macro test functions.  I've created about 30 new classes that all basically do nothing just to get strings that are being outputted into a specific file.  I would understand if you're confused as to why I'm doing this but it's something that needs to be done for a work project.

Comment: Due to the sensitivity of the task, I'm unable to provide the module macro function and there are no classes provided in the spreadsheet, just modules.  I've implemented all the classes thus far, but the simplified example above replicates the same process and error as the actual macro function.