# VBA Class to imitate primitive VBA datatype

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a VBA class where the class is instantiated with the `New` keyword but replicates a primitive VBA data type

Example:

```
Sub test()
    Dim replicate_double As New ClassDouble ' <- from some documentation I am referencing and attempting to replicate, it says that this class is a wrapper to a ClassVariant class module
    replicate_double = 2.234 ' <- should replicate as if doing a Double data type assignment
    Debug.Print replicate_double ' <- should print "2.234"
End Sub
```

I'm not entirely sure how to replicate this functionality but I've tried multiple things such as testing with a Property Set replicate_double() End Property. Passing parameters to the Class_initialize()

Comment: I guess you will need to define a *default member* for this class. See http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DefaultMember.aspx how to do so.

Comment: I'm attempting to copy what is in the link but excel keeps crashing when I attempt to import the .cls file.

Comment: You're a life saver, @FunThomas!  This is exactly what I needed.  This is my first time using VBA and I've spent 11 hours trying to figure this one problem out...

Out of curiosity, you wouldn't happen to know how to assign a class module without using the Set keyword, would you? My question in stackoverflow is pasted below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71577020/copy-or-reference-assignment-of-class-module

Comment: Just had a look to your other question, and no, it's simply not possible (others stated so). You need to use `Set` in VBA to assign object references. Since the beginning of Visual Basic (which is even older than VBA)

Comment: Good to know.  I do have an additional question regarding this stackoverflow question and I apologize for not asking in my initial question.  I got tunnel visioned.\  How could I do something like below?

Dim replicate_double As New ClassDouble
replicate_double (2.234)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a class with a default method for the value.  I prefer to use a factory class so that I can avoid the new statement at the point of construction.

Here is an example I've used for a class called 'oNumber'

```
VERSION 1.0 CLASS
BEGIN
  MultiUse = -1  'True
End
Attribute VB_Name = "oNumber"
Attribute VB_GlobalNameSpace = False
Attribute VB_Creatable = True
Attribute VB_PredeclaredId = True
Attribute VB_Exposed = True
Attribute VB_Description = "Class for managing number primitives"
Option Explicit
'@PredeclaredId
'@Exposed
'@ModuleDescription("Class for managing number primitives")

Private Type Properties
    
    Number                                  As Variant
    
End Type

Private p                               As Properties


Public Function Deb(ByVal ipNumber As Variant) As oNumber
    
    With New oNumber
    
        Set Deb = .ReadyToUseInstance(ipNumber)
    
    End With
    
End Function

' You could if you wanted add checks to the method below for ipNumber actually being a number
Friend Function ReadyToUseInstance(ByVal ipNumber As Variant) As oNumber
    p.Number = ipNumber
    Set ReadyToUseInstance = Me
End Function


'@DefaultMember
Public Property Get Value() As Variant
    Attribute Value.VB_VarUserMemId = 0
    Value =  p.Number
End Property


Public Property Set Value(ByVal ipNumber As Variant)
        p.Number = ipNumber
End Property

Public Function Clone() As oNumber
    Set Clone = oNumber.Deb(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function AsVarType() As VbVarType
    AsVarType = VarType(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function TypeName() As String
    TypeName = VBA.TypeName(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = CStr(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToByte() As Byte
    ToByte = CByte(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToDate() As Date
    ToDate = CDate(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToDecimal() As Decimal
    ToDecimal = CDec(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToDouble() As Double
    ToDouble = CDbl(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToInteger() As Integer
    ToInteger = CInt(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToLong() As Long
    ToLong = CLng(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToLongLong() As LongLong
    ToLongLong = CLngLng(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToLongPtr() As LongPtr
    ToLongPtr = CLngPtr(p.Number)
End Function

Public Function ToSingle() As Single
    ToSingle = CSng(p.Number)
End Function
```

In use you create a new oNumber as

```
Dim myNumber as oNumber
assign mynumber ,oNumber.deb(42)
```

but because the .Value method has been defined as a default member you can write the remainder of the code pretty much as normal

```
Dim myResult as oNumber
Set myResult = oNumber.Deb(0) ' oNumbers must alway be specifically initialised

myResult = myresult + 42

'Which is equivalent to 

myResult.Value = myResult.Value + 42
```

Good luck.

PS Please note the comments starting '@ are annotations used by the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA.  The annotations manage the Attribute statements that are not made visible in the VBA IDE but which still require setting to allow the above code to work as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what I am trying to achieve.  It needs to be done exactly how it is done in my original question.  I was able to achieve that by setting a default member in the class but now I am attempting to figure out how to do replicate_double (2.234)

Comment: The example I posted gives you all the information you need to achieve what you want.